# Trouble with simple arithmetic in perl

Tags: perl

At the moment I'm having trouble doing simple arithmetic seen in the code snippet below, I think the problem may be due to scope but I'm fairly new and don't fully comprehend the scope problem that I may be facing, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
use POSIX;
use integer;

my $firstnumber1 = 0;
my $secondnumber1 = 0;
my $digitcount = 0;

my $string = "ADD(5,4);";
if($string =~ /^ADD/)
{

      foreach my $char (split //, $string)
      {
          print "char = $char\n";
          if((isdigit($char)) && ($digitcount == 0))
          {

               $firstnumber1 = int($char);
               print "firstnumber = $firstnumber1\n";

          }
          if((isdigit($char)) && ($digitcount == 1))
          {
               $secondnumber1 = int($char);
               print "secondnumber = $secondnumber1\n";
          }
          $digitcount++;
          my $finalnumber1 = $firstnumber1 + $secondnumber1
      }


}
print "$finalnumber1 = $firstnumber1 + $secondnumber1";
```

Comment: There is no `$finalnumber1`. You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`

Comment: Finally! I got it to work. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `$digitCount` increment should be inside the two if blocks. Right now you'll increment it when you process the `A` and then on the `D`, etc. so by the time you get to the `5` `$digitCount` will be 4 and you're if conditions will never be true.

Comment: Alrighty, so I moved the increment into when the $digitcount should be 0 and then I moved the block when $digitcount is 1 to the top because it was hitting the second if statement. Now I'm correctly getting the first and second digits but it's still not outputting final number correctly.

Comment: You'll want to read @Borodin's comment. $finalNumber1 isn't in scope when you print it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a parser in a language you don't fully know yet. Parsers are *hard*, so I think you should start with something else

You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write. That would have alerted you top `finalnumber1` not being declared. And all declarations should be made as *late* as possible -- usually where they are first defined

It's not clear what you intended to happen after the second number! Don't use overly long identifiers like `$firstnumber1` etc., and if you find that you're using identifiers with numbers at the end then it's a sign that you need an *array* instead

Here's my take on what you were trying to do

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10;

my ($n1, $n2);
my $nc = 0;
my $total = 0;

my $string = 'ADD(5,4);';

if ( $string =~ /^ADD/ ) {

    for my $char ( split //, $string ) {

        say "char = $char";

        if ( $char =~ /[0-9]/ ) {

            if ( $nc == 0 ) {
                $n1 = $char;
                say "firstnumber = $n1";
            }
            else {
                $n2 = $char;
                say "secondnumber = $n2";
            }

            $total += $char;
            ++$nc;
        }
    }
}

say "$total = $n1 + $n2";
```

### output

```
char = A
char = D
char = D
char = (
char = 5
firstnumber = 5
char = ,
char = 4
secondnumber = 4
char = )
char = ;
9 = 5 + 4
```